# Using Socat Listening Multiple Port (Port Range)

Tags: socat

I have `Socat` command as follow :

```
socat -u TCP4-LISTEN:5000,reuseaddr,fork OPEN:/tmp/test1-2039-sip-i,creat,append
```

And I would like to modify to listen to many ports range, from port `10000 till 29999`

What is the right command to fullfill that need?

Answer (score 1):

yes, socat can only listen on one port at a time per instance so my amateur method for getting around this is is using an array in a bash script to open an instance of socat for each port I need to monitor. Doing this for thousands of ports isn't really practical, since while socat uses little resources when listening, running 20,000 instances of socat is impractical, but i've run 50 at a single time on a small SoC board. So name your defined ports in an array (ports that are actually used), then iterate through a bash array loop and spawn a few instances.

```
#!/bin/bash
ports=( 23 24 25 443 80 )
for port in "${ports[@]}"; do 
socat tcp-listen:$port,reuseaddr,fork open:/tmp/$port.txt,creat,append
done
exit
```

This writes data coming in from the ports to "port number file".txt in /tmp, ie. 24.txt. If you get an error, it's because something else has bonded to the port already.  Use inotifywatch to alert you when a file gets written to.

This question has been out here a while and it keeps coming up in my searches. So I decided to answer it.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I am also stuck around this. On my Ubuntu machine I need to forward all ipv4 traffic on any port to the same port on ipv6. with socat I managed to create few instances but I actually need all the 65000 ports to be forwarded. Please share if you know of a tool that can do this!

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork TCP:host1:8080 | socat TCP-LISTEN:8081,fork TCP:host2:8082
```

It forward the 8080 port to host1:8080 and also the 8081 to host2:8082 and can be more with add `|` in single line.

Comment: Isn't this only one way socket? What if bidirectional is required?

Comment: @AnttiRytsölä I don't understand about bidirectional communication. Because in this command, socat only delivers tcp from one port to the destination port, and in fact a redirect takes place.